# How to programmatically focus into next input element after typing a single character in ios mobile using angular 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have several input fields like below.

```
<input type='text' autocapitalize='off' ng-keypress='validateAnswer($event)' id='single_char_box_1'  class='form-control' ng-model='charValues[0]' size='1' maxlength='1'  />
<input type='text' autocapitalize='off' ng-keypress='validateAnswer($event)' id='single_char_box_2'  class='form-control' ng-model='charValues[1]' size='1' maxlength='1'  />
<input type='text' autocapitalize='off' ng-keypress='validateAnswer($event)' id='single_char_box_3'  class='form-control' ng-model='charValues[2]' size='1' maxlength='1'  />
```

In my controller I have the following code:

```
$scope.validateAnswer = function($event){
            var regex = new RegExp("[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]");

            var key = String.fromCharCode(!$event.charCode ? $event.which : $event.charCode);

            if (!regex.test(key)) {
               $event.preventDefault();
               return false;
            }else{

                var next_element = document.getElementById($event.target.attributes.autoTabTo.nodeValue);

                if (next_element) {

                    next_element.focus();

                }


            }
        };
```

Above code works fine in the web browser, but in the **Ipad**(chrome browser) it behaves differently. It jumps to the second input when you type a character in the **first input**. It doesn't display any character in the **first input**.

Comment: It is because you are using `ng-kepress` try to use `ng-keyup`.

Comment: Thanks @ahsanayub it worked. :)